# replacing column and row with another value

Tags: python

Can someone please tell me why is `board[x-1][y-1] == "x"` not executing? I've been at this for a while now. The error I get is: `TypeError: 'str' does not support item assignment.` I would like to be able to place an "x" on the row and column that the player chooses.

Here's the code:

```
import random

board = []

for i in range(3):
    board.append("|___|"*3)
for row in board:
    print row

x = int(raw_input("x: "))
y = int(raw_input("y: "))

board[x-1][y-1] = "x"
```

One of Codecademy's exercises has a similar if not identical line of code but I don't know why mine doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Well, board is a 1-dimentional list, it doesn't contain two dimentions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to edit a string. This is because you initialized a `1-D` not `2-D` list.

To initialize a `2-D` list, do it as follows:

```
for i in range(3):
    board.append(["|___|"]*3)   # Note the [] around the "|___|"
```

When you print your board, it should look like this:

```
['|___|', '|___|', '|___|']
['|___|', '|___|', '|___|']
['|___|', '|___|', '|___|']
```

Then your code will work fine

Comment: can you please explain what [] around the "|___|" means? and what is the difference between a 1-D and 2-D list?

Comment: @jasonadams, It means to create a list of 3 `"|___|"` and in your code you do this command 3 times to get a `3X3` board

Comment: @jasonadams, A 1-D list is: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` whereas a 2-D list is: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` Basically lists within a list.

Comment: ok, I see, so everytime I would like to do a 2D list I would need to include []? is this correct?

Comment: @jasonadams, Well not necessarily. For example: the following produces a 1-D list: `[0]*3` as `[0,0,0]` and the following produces a 2-D list: `[[1,2]]*3` as `[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]`. Hope that is clear

Comment: @jasonadams, I suggest looking at some examples online. Best way to understand is to experiment with them. Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

```
board[x-1][y-1] = "x"
```

Board is a one dimentional list. Look at it this way:

```
board[0] = "|___||___||___|"
```

What you'd want is probably:

```
board[0] = ["|___|", "|___|", "|___|"]
```

Try this:

```
import random

board = []

for i in range(3):
    if len(board)-1 < i: board.append([])
    board[i] = []
    columns = board[i]
    for colNum in range(3):
        columns.append('|___|')
    board[i] = columns

for row in board:
    print(row)

x = int(raw_input("x: "))
y = int(raw_input("y: "))

board[x-1][y-1] = "| x |"

# To verify the change:
for row in board:
    print(row)
```